# How can i give position coordinates relative to the center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

I'm creating a page where I want an image to slightly move on mouse hover, like a parallax effect.

So what I already managed to put the image slightly moving. What I did was associating the image position to the mouse coordinates (which I already noticed my mistake). What happens is that the images almost leaves the viewpoint, because it goes to the actual position I gave. I tried to give the image a negative margin with no success.

The output I'm looking for is when the user's mouse hover the image, it will follow the mouse direction by just a few pixels and when the user stops hovering it, the image should return to its original position.

How do I solve this?

```js
$('.img-top').mousemove(function(e) {
  var x = -(e.pageX + this.offsetLeft) / 100;
  var y = -(e.pageY + this.offsetTop) / 100;
  $(this).css('left', x + 'px ');
  $(this).css('top', y + 'px ');
});
```

```css
.img-top {
  height: 75vh;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  //    margin-left: -50vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="full-img img-top lrrh" src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x400/000/fff" alt="image alt descrp">
```

Comment: I'm afraid your description is a little bit vague. Can you elaborate a little - e.g. where it should move, how fast, how far - what should happen it the user moves the mouse away..

Comment: @mnponte I created a `jsfiddle` for you, since your image is local to your server/project I added one using an image src from W3Schools, perhaps this will help in testing and solving for your solution. (https://jsfiddle.net/1gn2o6v5/)

Comment: @obscure I just updated my question. I hope it's more clarifying now

Comment: I've added a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) of your code so that people can edit on this site without going elsewhere. You may want to use an absolute URL to the image desired, or use something like https://dummyimage.com/

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, I added an additional event handler for when the mouse leaves the image. It then clears out the css which is added by the mousemove event. I added some additional CSS to clean up the example and make things more visible as they occur.

```js
$('.img-top').mousemove(function(e) {
  var x = ((e.pageX) + (this.offsetLeft)) / 100;
  var y = ((e.pageY) + (this.offsetTop)) / 100;
  $(this).css('left', x + 'px ');
  $(this).css('top', y + 'px ');
  
  update_info($(this), e);
});

$('.img-top').mouseleave(function(e) {
  $(this).css('left', '0px');
  $(this).css('top', '0px');
  
  update_info($(this), e);
});

function update_info(e, m) {
  var i = $('.info'),
      o = e.offset();
      i.empty().append(''
      +'<p>[Image] x: '+Math.round(o.left)+'px - y: '+Math.round(o.top)+'px</p>'
      +'<p>[Mouse] x: '+Math.round(m.pageX)+'px - y: '+Math.round(m.pageY)+'px</p>');
}
```

```css
.fill {
  background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.image-viewpane {
  display:inline-block;
  height:200px;
  width:600px;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  border:4px solid red;
}

.img-top {
  position:relative; 
  display:inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width:auto;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 4px rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fill">
  <div class="image-viewpane">
    <img class="img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x400/000/fff" alt="image alt descrp"/>
  </div> 
  <div class="info"><p>Waiting for mouse movement ...</p></div>
</div>
```